# This conducts both ways. What is it?

Tags: current

[image]

What is this? It conducts both ways.

Comment: Hard to tell from the blurry picture. Can you take another picture?

Comment: What is the resistance? I'm guessing it is quite low (less than 1 Ohm). I'm also guessing that this isn't really a component but just a **wire** made into a loop with a hole, that is sometimes used to **connect the probe of an oscilloscope**.

Comment: Ooops. I voted to close as "needs details or clarity". I should have selected "needs more focus". While you're at it, crop the photo properly. > 90% of what you posted is irrelevant background.

Comment: its a test point

Comment: Good question! Concur @Bimpelrekkie. We should call it test point/test clip/test post/probe point/etc.

Comment: https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/Keystone-Electronics/5000?qs=q0tsjPZWdm%252B9SiiTAbEwUw%3D%3D

Comment: This question ***seriously*** needs more clarity in words and images.

Comment: if it conducts  both ways it is a resistor

Comment: All - *Please be nice* and comply with the site's [Code of Conduct](/help/conduct) in everything you write. Nothing snarky / sarcastic / condescending (or worse). Some comments were already flagged by other site members & deleted. Yes, it's a poor photo, but that was stated in the 1st comment. No need to "pile onto" the OP. [Polite, constructive criticism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756) is allowed - with the emphasis on *polite & constructive*. It's also sad to see so many users breaking those site rules for the use of comments, by answering in comments.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a fuzzy macro photo of 5 mm case with possibly bi-colored LEDS made by BIVAR.